# character strings into arrays

Tags: c

This is/isn't homework...the printing of the list IS homework and that works great, the iscntrl() and Array stuff is 6 weeks from now stuff and giving me grief.

I want to create an array filled with the first 32 TLAs of the Ascii table so that when I print out a column / row chart of Decimal to Ascii code I can use iscntrl() to flag that it's an un-printable character.  In its place I want to grab the next TLA in the array and print that instead of the non-graphical character.

I have the iscntrl() working fine.  Just can't figure out the array thing.  All the examples in the books I have and online want to demo grabbing input from the user and tossing it into the array.  I want to give the array a list at the beginning in the code and pull from that.

Can someone either give me a good link for what I need or just tell me how to do the whole process?

I've got 32 three letter items and I need to populate the array and pull them out via a **for loop**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare an array like this, and pre-fill its values:

```
const char *ControlCharacterNames[] = {
    "NUL",
    "SOH",
    "STX",
    "ETX",
    // etc
};
```

Then, you can access `ControlCharacterNames` as an array in your code.

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much!  Now I won't be awake all night pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 3):

http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html, chapter "6.7.2. More initialization".

Long story short, you probably need something like

```
char *TLAs[] = { "TL1", "TL2", "TL3", "FYI", "WTH", /* ...and so on...*/ };
```

and then pull the one you need using it's index

```
printf(TLAs[3]); // print "FYI", the 4th TLA
```

Hope I understood your question right.

Comment: Okay, I need to start typing this stuff faster.